# How to Update ViewModel without Using Mapping

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, knockout.js

I have a knockout ViewModel that has a few observables, some observable arrays that have observables.

```
var FulfillRequistionRequestModel = function (data) {
    data = data || {}; var self = {};

    self.RequisitionId = ko.observable(data.RequisitionId || null);
    self.FulfillItemList    = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(data.FulfillItemList, function (item_list) { return new FulfillItemModel(item_list); })
    );
    self.NumberOfItems = ko.computed(function () { return self.FulfillItemList().length; });

    //add-remove FullfillItem in FulfillItemList (this is per line number)
    self.removeItemFromList = function (fulfill_item) { self.FulfillItemList.remove(fulfill_item); };
    self.addItemToList = function () { self.FulfillItemList.push(new FulfillItemModel()); };

    return self;
};

var FulfillItemModel = function (data) {
    data = data || {}; var self = {};

    self.BoxNumber      = ko.observable(data.BoxNumber                  || null);
    self.LineNumber     = ko.observable(data.LineNumber                 || null);
    self.SourceBin      = ko.observable(new BinModel(data.SourceBin)    || null);
    self.ItemDetailList = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(data.ItemDetailList, function (item_list) { return new ItemDetailModel(item_list); })
    );
    self.NumberOfItems = ko.computed(function () {return self.ItemDetailList().length;});

    //add-remove something from ItemDetailList (ItemDetail)
    self.removeItemFromList = function (item) { self.ItemDetailList.remove(item); };
    self.addItemToList = function () { self.ItemDetailList.push(new ItemDetailModel()); };

    return self;
};
var ItemDetailModel = function(data) {
    data = data || {}; var self = {};

    self.Part           = ko.observable(data.Part           || null);
    self.Owner          = ko.observable(data.Owner          || null);
    self.Condition      = ko.observable(data.Condition      || null);
    self.Bcn            = ko.observable(data.Bcn            || null);
    self.SerialNumber   = ko.observable(data.SerialNumber   || null);
    self.Quantity       = ko.observable(data.Quantity       || null);

    return self;
};

var myModel = new FulfillRequistionRequestModel(thing);
ko.applyBindings(myModel);
```

You get the idea.   I have a ViewModel that has a few observables, and then an observablearray made up of a collection of observables (ItemModel).

Here's a sample of the JSON it's consuming:

```
var thing = {
    RequisitionId: 55,
    FulfillItemList: [
        {
            BoxNumber: 555,
            LineNumber: 001,
            SourceBin: { Location: "Jason", Warehouse: "AMERICA" },
            ItemDetailList: [
                { Part: "999-JASONTEST-111", Condition: "OLD" },
                { Part: "999-JASONTEST-115", Quantity: 55 }
            ]

        },
        {
            BoxNumber: 444,
            LineNumber: 002,
            SourceBin: { Location: "Jason", Warehouse: "CANADA" },
            ItemDetailList: [
                { Part: "999-JASONTEST-221", Condition: "NEW" },
                { Part: "999-JASONTEST-225", Bcn: "ABC123", Condition:"BUSTED", Quantity: 23 },
                { Part: "999-JASONTEST-228", Quantity: 55 }
            ]

        }
    ]
};
```

Imagine this as an "order".   Someone clicks an order ID, and it loads the relevant information.   I want it, so that if they click another order ID -- the view model is updated with that information (a new JSON from an AJAX call).

**EVERYWHERE** I see, says use the `ko.mapping.fromJS(newJSON, mapping, viewModel);` format -- but I bit the bullet, and am not mapping my ViewModel with ko.mapping this time, I spent the time building it out so I could really flex its muscles, and ko.mapping won't seem to work on my hand-built MVVM.

So - lets say I get a new top-level data - how can I refresh `myModel` so that it's all working?

I've tried even just setting `myModel = {}` or `myModel = new FulfillRequisitionRequestModel({});` just to see if I could zero out the elements/page - but that seems to break the `.applyBindings`, as the page stops responding - is no longer connected.

So -- i have `myModel` - and it is working great.    It's an "order" with a list of things in that order (products, say) - and customer info.   How do I load a new order into the model?

I *really* don't want to tear down and "reset" every sub-observable.   I'd like to just refresh it, like `ko.mapping` does -- and frankly, if I have to walk through and clean house - what's the point?   Head back to ko.mapping and let it handle all that.

So - with my carefully constructed viewmodel - how can I update it with a whole set of new data coming from AJAX/REST (it's JSON) -- like `ko.mapping.fromJS` does?

Answer (score 0):

This was really frustrating, and [RP Niemeyer led me on the right path](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html) with using `ko.utils.extend` to extend refreshing externally.   that didn't work for me so well, and it's probably due to my references of `self`, `this`, and `return self` inside each object.

Essentially, I changed my `FulfillRequistionRequestModel` (the top dog) to :

```
var FulfillRequistionRequestModel = function (data) {
    data = data || {}; var self = {};

    self.RequisitionId      = ko.observable();      //neutered
    self.FulfillItemList    = ko.observableArray(); //neutered

    self.NumberOfItems      = ko.computed(function () { return self.FulfillItemList().length; });

    //add-remove FullfillItem in FulfillItemList (this is per line number)
    self.removeItemFromList = function (fulfill_item) { self.FulfillItemList.remove(fulfill_item); };
    self.addItemToList      = function () { self.FulfillItemList.push(new FulfillItemModel()); };


    //allow self updates
    self.update = function (data) {
        data = data || {};
        self.FulfillItemList.removeAll(); self.RequisitionId(data.RequisitionId || null);
        if (data.FulfillItemList) {
            $.each(data.FulfillItemList, function (i, item) {
                self.FulfillItemList.push(new FulfillItemModel(item));
            });
        }
    }; if (data) { self.update(data); } //this handles first-construction (.applyBinding)

    return self;
};
```

You'll note with this, I've set up the two main observable properties as just empties (the `RequisitionId` and `FulfillItemList`) -- and then created a `self.update` function that will reset those fields to content or null, depending on what's passed in.   I'm sure there's probably something more elegant than using `$.each` to push.   Maybe `ko.utils.arrayMap` or some such, but this works.

**TLDR:**
I created an update routine inside the viewmodel.   This isn't perfect, because it now has that when I `ko.mapping.toJS` it, to send it back to C#/REST-API, but that's also just fine because the way it consumes it, it ignores any extras.

```
public IHttpActionResult testloadpart(FulfillRequisitionRequest incoming) {
//do stuff
//incoming.update does not exist.
//incoming.NumberOfItems does not exist.
//incoming.RequisitionId DOES exist

}


public partial class FulfillRequisitionRequest {

    [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    public long RequisitionId { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayAttribute(Order = 1)]
    [XmlArrayItemAttribute("FulfillItem", IsNullable = false)]
    public List<fulfillItem> FulfillItemList { get; set; }

    public FulfillRequisitionRequest() {
        FulfillItemList = new List<fulfillItem>();
    }
}
```